# Increase number of parallel tasks in Standalone mode

Tags: apache-spark

I have java application in development stage. And I have remote spark cluster in Cluster Standalone mode that includes only one machine with 2 processor cores. "cluster" contains master and one worker. Application sends long running jobs and jobs are not demanding for CPU work but make many calls to remote services. In other words I use spark like tasks scheduler.
During testing I see that application sends for example 5 tasks in the same time, but only 2 can work in parallel, another 3 are in the queue. Question is it possible to increase number of parallel tasks in this configuration with one instance with 2 physical cores?

Comment: Have you tried setting `spark.executor.cores` to a higher value ?

Comment: @Dikei Do you mean to pass this property to JavaSparkContext on my application side? If I do it the job can't be submitted without any errors

Answer (score 0):

To increase the number of parallel task you have to increase physical cores. As you have 2 cores 2 tasks are running parallel and other 3 are in queue.